# Creating dictionary for area calculation of Resolve Ecoregions (vector)

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

I'd like to calculate area by Ecoregion dataset and create a dictionary for each class as well.
I'd like to also select particular metadata within this dataset (e.g: `BIOME_NAME`)
However, I haven't found how to clip and calculate area using vector files in Earth Engine.

```
//** Center on the Region of Interest
Map.centerObject (roi,10);

//** Import Ecoregion
var ecoRegions = ee.FeatureCollection("RESOLVE/ECOREGIONS/2017")
                .filterBounds (roi);
print (ecoRegions);

//** Set up color
var colorUpdates = [
                  {ECO_ID: 204, COLOR: '#B3493B'},
                  {ECO_ID: 245, COLOR: '#267400'},
                  {ECO_ID: 259, COLOR: '#004600'},
                  {ECO_ID: 286, COLOR: '#82F178'},
                  {ECO_ID: 316, COLOR: '#E600AA'},
                  {ECO_ID: 453, COLOR: '#5AA500'},
                  {ECO_ID: 317, COLOR: '#FDA87F'},
                  {ECO_ID: 763, COLOR: '#A93800'},
                  ];

//** loop over all other features and create a new style property for styling
//** later on
var ecoRegions = ecoRegions.map(function(f) {
  var color = f.get('COLOR');
  return f.set({style: {color: color, width: 0}});
});

//** make styled features for the regions we need to update colors for,
//** then strip them from the main asset and merge in the new feature
for (var i=0; i < colorUpdates.length; i++) {
  colorUpdates[i].layer = ecoRegions
      .filterMetadata('ECO_ID','equals',colorUpdates[i].ECO_ID)
      .map(function(f) {
        return f.set({style: {color: colorUpdates[i].COLOR, width: 0}});
      });

  ecoRegions = ecoRegions
      .filterMetadata('ECO_ID','not_equals',colorUpdates[i].ECO_ID)
      .merge(colorUpdates[i].layer);
}

//** Use style property to color shapes
var imageRGB = ecoRegions.style({styleProperty: 'style'});

//** Visualize the Ecoregion dataset
Map.addLayer(imageRGB.clip(roi), {}, 'RESOLVE/ECOREGIONS/2017');

//** Create List
var list = ecoRegions.toList(10,0)
print ('--Resolve Ecoregion 2017 by AOI--', list)

``
How do I complete this script?
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, not sure what exactly you want to do, but here is an example. I have added some links in the code so that you can read about the procedure.

```
// Define ROI
var roi = ee.Geometry.Rectangle(86, 18, 93, 25);
Map.centerObject (roi,5);

// Filter using metadata
var ecoRegions = ee.FeatureCollection("RESOLVE/ECOREGIONS/2017");
var tropical = ecoRegions
          .filter(ee.Filter.eq('BIOME_NAME','Tropical & Subtropical Moist Broadleaf Forests'))
          .filterBounds(roi);

 var clipped = tropical.map(function(f){ return f.intersection(roi,1)});

Map.addLayer(clipped,{},'tropical');



 // Functions to select regions based on 'BIOME_NAME' and calculate area
var getRegions = function(image){
var selectRegions = ee.FeatureCollection("RESOLVE/ECOREGIONS/2017")
                    .filter(ee.Filter.eq('BIOME_NAME','Tropical & Subtropical Moist 
Broadleaf Forests'))
                    .filterBounds (roi);
  return image.reduceRegions({
collection: selectRegions,
reducer: ee.Reducer.sum(),
scale: 1000  // scale in meters 
  });
};


var areaIamge = ee.Image.pixelArea();

 //Aplly function
 var stats = getRegions(areaIamge); // Use Export.table.. 

 print('Print:',stats.first()); // Area is the last property named 'sum'
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/b75f2bfb590544ffdff6f664d7e187a1